# Problems creating a Live USB for OS X from Linux Fedora 25

Tags: terminal, usb, startup, unix

I've been considering to move from OS X to Linux, because I want to have full control over the source code of the os and the apps I use, and Linux and open-source software allows me that in general, without having to go against the EULA.

Bearing this in mind, I installed Fedora 25 on my Mac. I created a Live USB, with the given app for OS X, which I used to boot. I had no problems doing so, but after a while I started feeling like the os was not only comprising my hardware stability, but also there were a few tiny little bugs, which I didn't want to mess around. Furthermore, two days after installing the os, I had problems with the boot loader, and I had to format the computer again. Furthermore, I don't have graphics acceleration in my graphics card, and the Planet CCRMA repositories, which were the main reason why I moved to fedora 25, don't seem to work on my install.

Bearing all of this in mind, I want to know how can I move back to OS X, creating an OS X installer thumb drive straight in Linux. I tried doing so throughout three possible ways:

1. I tried to run createinstallmedia from the installaton disk, which didn't work out (I currently have a hard drive in the place of the dvd drive) - the command for doing so doesn't run in Linux, because it cannot run the specific binaries.
2. I tried to create an install media with `sudo dd if=x of=y`, straight after using dmg2iso command but it turned out not to work, simply because this has to be done using the predeceasing bash utility.
3. Finally, I tried to use an app called [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/), but for some reason, it doesn't recognize the USB disk I need to use as a target, making it worthless (probably the software is needing some maintainance to work fine on Fedora 25)

Comment: my mac model is basically a1278

Comment: A1278 include mid2008 - mid 2012 MBPs.  All Macs built after ~2010/2011 can boot to Internet Recovery Mode and reinstall OS X. So add something like MBP 13" Late 2011.

Comment: the problem is that i accidentally removed my recovery partition. fedora installer did it. so i really need a live usb. i have an iso containing the os, i just need to burn it properly to an usb drive, which i also have. but i need to do that from linux, which is the only os i currently have available

Comment: so, can you please tell me how can i access this mode? kind regards. tiago

Comment: command option r, i've seen it. going to try it now

Comment: I am installing it al re e

Comment: it would just be interesting if it would install the most recent version of the os for you automatically, without needing to upgrade it

Comment: yes, i was using internet recovery, should now switch to recovery mode, and upgrade. but having an old os, on a robust machine, is sometimes a good idea, so i will see as it goes. thank you.

Comment: Please write an answer to answer your own question!

Comment: never heard of linux on mac hardware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to **klanomath**, i realized that there was a much simpler way to fix this issue. it basically consists of: pressing **alt command r** in boot, to enter **internet recovery.** please notice that this will only work in macintosh **computers released after 2010-2011.** after doing so, the computer will connect to the internet and you will be able to **download the stock version of your os from the cloud**. after doing so, **install it,** then boot into the os. if it is like a really old version, you can boot into **recovery mode** (now installed). and **download the latest version**. if this procedure doesn't work, you can also **download the latest version of macosx**, and using **createinstallmedia** command in installation media, and **install the latest version of osx**